# How write characters to TelnetOutputStream one at a time?

Tags: java, apache-commons, telnet, outputstream

I am using `apache.commons.net.telnet`.

I have `char[] array`. I am calling `TelnetClient.getOutputStream().write(array[i]).`

I expected that my data will be sent by one character at a time, but Wireshark shows that first character is sent alone, and remaining characters are sent together.
Why do I get this situation and how can I send my data character by character?

Comment: Did you already try Outputstream.flush() after write()?

Comment: Yes, i call `flush()` after `write()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Here is the correct answer. To send the data as fast as possible,  do the following:

Call setTcpNoDelay(true) on your output stream.

Call write with your entire array. You should NEWER EVER write one byte at a time. Writing the entire array at the same time will be much faster.

Call flush() after your write.

This is the fastest way to send the data, and it is also the way which will create the least latency. That is: Sending the bytes one at a time will NOT ensure that the server will receive them any faster.

Sending the data one byte at a time will slow you down, not speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `flush()` after each call to write()?

`flush()` function should send anything in the stream before the buffer is filled.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to send the chars one at a time(Why, it will really slow you down) I guess you have to iterate over the array and call write with a single byte each time. And then flush after each write. Something like (Not tested, but it should give you the a hint).

```
OutputStream os=TelnetClient.getOutputStream();
for(int i=0;i!=array.length;i++) {
  os.write(array[i]);
  os.flush();
}
```

Comment: That may be because your os keeps data waiting for more data before sending it. Just a a test, try to add a call to Thread.sleep(10) after each flush. But I still don't understand why you want to do this. Sending your data one byte at a time, will take at least 100 times as long as sending it all at once.

Comment: I need to receive response from telnet server in real-time!

Comment: It really depends of time between calling write(). If i call Thread.sleep(10) it works the same way, but if i call Thread.sleep(200) characters are sent one at a time. It is possible to get around this?

Comment: In realtime?? Sending the bytes one at a time will not give you any faster response.

Comment: I told incorrectly. I need to send data not only after '\n' character input. For example, if i have typed '?' telnet server should respond me with help message, not after typing '?\n'.